# Streaming .pls on android via phonegap

Tags: android, webkit, cordova

I have this link : xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:yyyy/listen.pls and I want to stream it on my android device. I am using PhoneGap (HTML/CSS/JS). How to do it?
***_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*____**-
Nevermined I found solution:
just remove listen.pls and it works fine.

```
    var media = new Media("http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:yyyy");
    media.play();
```